# Changing text, the layout changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

If I change the text of a label, its container changes position. (Auto layout)
My simple code:

```
BOOL nextCard = [self loadCardInfo:card];

    if (nextCard == TRUE) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

            [card setFrame:CGRectMake(hideCardPosition.x, hideCardPosition.y, card.frame.size.width, card.frame.size.height)];

        }completion:^(BOOL complete){
        }];
}
```

the problem is at last line:

```
-(BOOL)loadCardInfo:(CardView*)card {

if (dataArray.count > 0) {

    card.string = [dataArray objectAtIndex:0];
    [dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    card.label.text = card.string; //THIS LINE

    return YES;

} else

    return NO;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please share the auto layout. Proper use of layout constraints can keep the text at a fixed position. To achieve this it should be beneficial to see your Interface Builder screen.

Comment: Sure http://s27.postimg.org/dzspeozcj/image.png http://s22.postimg.org/xtf5b8nht/image.png

Comment: Thx, can u also share the fully opened tree hierarchy of this view, next to the designer on the left

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve in the `+UIView animateWithDuration:animations:` call but you probably don't want to be mixing Auto Layout with manually setting the frame like you are in the `animations` block.
Best practice is (usually) to stick with one or the other.
Also, perhaps you want some sort of vertical Auto Layout constraints (pinning to superview or setting a height?)